# Laser printer pages covered with toner powder. What to replace first?

Tags: printer, repair, laser-printer

I'm working on a [Dell 2150cn color laser printer](http://www.dell.com/ed/p/dell-2150cn/pd). It is only about two years old but the one year factory warranty has expired.

**Symptom:** When printing a page the paper comes out covered in dry toner powder. There isn't even a semblance of the image or text that should appear, just a fairly even random coating of powder (think white noise). This happens even when printing a report page directly from the printer so it's definitely a hardware problem. The printer doesn't report any errors.

**What I've tried:** I logged into the printer's web interface and reset everything to defaults and tried all the cleaning options under printer maintenance. No change in behavior.

**What should I try next?**

The troubleshooting scenarios relating to print quality in the manual suggest replacing the [print head device/imaging drum](http://accessories.us.dell.com/sna/productdetail.aspx?c=us&l=en&s=bsd&cs=04&sku=331-0711).

I'm leaning towards replacing the [fuser](http://accessories.us.dell.com/sna/productdetail.aspx?c=us&l=en&s=dhs&cs=19&sku=332-0860) instead since nothing is sticking to the page at all but I don't have much experience working on laser printers so I'm asking here!

Comment: Sounds to me like you have more of a problem than the fuser... There should be a fairly well-formed image on the paper even if the fuser isn't working. I'd guess there's a problem with the controller electronics since both the laser/belt stage and the fuser stage aren't working.

Comment: @BobT Thanks for that info. If there are multiple things wrong it might be cheaper to just replace the entire printer.

Comment: Something to be considered... HP has some relatively cheap color printers (selling at almost the cost of the cartridges).